# how to send multipart data and text data from html form to jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, file-upload

How to send multipart data and text data from HTML form  to JSP page at time

my form field are Name ,upload file

I am unable to send both at a time

Comment: Please provide some more information. Some code will be good.

Answer (score 0):

In a `multipart/form-data` request, the text parameter is *also* sent as a multipart item, not as a regular query parameter. To get the text parameter, you need to use the **same** API as you have used to get the uploaded file. Assuming that you're using [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload), which is a de facto standard `multipart/form-data` parser, then you need to hook on the condition where the item is a normal form field.

```
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem item : items) {
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
        String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
        String fieldvalue = item.getString();
        // ... (do your job here)
    } else {
        // Process form file field (input type="file").
        String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
        String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
        InputStream filecontent = item.getInputStream();
        // ... (do your job here)
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)